# Cloud Spanner - Insert or Update and Increment DML?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to use DML to "insert or (update and **increment**)" rows in Google Cloud Spanner?

This doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO table (key, value) VALUES ('ABC', 1) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + 1
# Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [Data Manipulation Language syntax](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-syntax) informs:

> If the statement attempts to insert a duplicate row, as determined by the primary key, then the entire statement fails.

So, it's not possible to insert using this type of function that you are trying, unfortunately.

I would recommend you to take a look at this documentation - [Inserting, updating, and deleting data using Data Manipulation Language](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-tasks) - to get more information, on using DML with Cloud Spanner.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you. Do you see any other way, e.g. through Mutations, to achieve what I'm looking for? Otherwise, do you see any other Google Cloud Service that could do that? Looks like even BigTable doesn't support `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Hi @user9114945 ! Unfortunately, as far as I know, there isn't a way to achieve that. I would recommend you to open a Feature Request at [Report Issues and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) since it seems to be a good addition to the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with DML, but you can do it with the Spanner mutations API. Comparison of the feature set available in each paradigm: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-versus-mutations#feature_comparison_between_dml_and_mutations

For example, using the Go client library:

```
func write(w io.Writer, db string) error {
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := spanner.NewClient(ctx, db)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        defer client.Close()

        singerColumns := []string{"SingerId", "FirstName", "LastName"}
        m := []*spanner.Mutation{
                spanner.InsertOrUpdate("Singers", singerColumns, []interface{}{1, "Marc", "Richards"}),
                spanner.InsertOrUpdate("Singers", singerColumns, []interface{}{2, "Catalina", "Smith"}),
        }
        _, err = client.Apply(ctx, m)
        return err
}
```